# Mobile browser rejects CSS update

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have redesigned my website by changing around colours and components to better suited my theme. However, when accessing this from my mobile browser, only some of the changes show. These changes were done using on the fly styling. 
I have tried clearing the cache in my mobile device and have tried the website on other mobile devices as well.

Why does the mobile browser not correctly receive the CSS updates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like you are using adaptive templates rather than responsive

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is no magic, if you update your CSS file, push it to the server and invalidate the old CSS file your new styles will show up. Perhaps you didn't use media queries properly? Hard to know with out an MCVE.

Comment: What you mean with "on the fly"? Inline styles?

Comment: Yes. In line code. I have, however, sorted it out using grunt asset versioning

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem like you before, then I tried to use [grunt asset versioning](https://github.com/theasta/grunt-assets-versioning) and it worked on mine, so maybe you can use that for your problem.

Comment: Thank you. It has been sorted out. I appreciate your help